# Утилита diff. Нужны соображения по реализации.

Tags: linux, c, diff

Планирую взять это задание в качестве курсовой. Нужно реализовать на языке С. У кого-нибудь есть идеи. Погуглив, я нашел статью в вики. У меня есть идея посмотреть реализацию оригинальную (её я пока не нашел, скорее всего найду, но если кто поможет с ссылкой, то спасибо большое)

Comment: у гугла есть хороший сервис google.com/codesearch Вбей там diff.c и сразу получишь кучу эталонных реализаций.

Comment: А еще у гугла есть отличный сервис http://scholar.google.ch/ где можна найти кучу материала.

Comment: А еще надо ходить на лекции к Андрею Леонидовичу, тогда будет возникать меньше вопросов. Как раз недавно он обьяснял что нужно делать в курсовых и направлял куда копать

Answer (score 3):

Можете ещё копнуть в сторону [оригинальных GNU diffutils](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/diffutils-3.0.tar.gz) (которые и содержат diff)

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверить размер файлов. Разный размер -> файлы разные.
2. Проверить MD5/CRC файлов. Если разные -> файлы разные. При этом одинаковость хешей ни о чем не говорит, кроме как о высокой вероятности совпадения файлов.
3. Построчно или побайтово (посимвольно!?) сравниваем файлы. Каждое отличие выводим в stdout.